# asp.net Post Multiple Data into Multiple Tables at once using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Imagine a situation where I need to post multiple Data into Multiple Tables. Here is one example to illustrate the situation:

Suppose I want `CustomerName` and `Orders` all at same page and Save them just in one `Save` click; Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <span class="col-md-12">Customer Name</span>
        <input type="text" id="customername"/>
    </div>
    <div id="ulist">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
                        <span>Order Name</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <span>Order Number</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderNumber)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
                        <span>Order Name</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <span>Order Number</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderNumber)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="max-width:100%; margin-top:10px;" onclick="AddInfo()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is OrderList View Model:

```
public class OrderListVM
{
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string DataJson { get; set; }
}
```

This is SaveCustomer Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public int SaveCustomerOnlyFirst(string CustomerName)
{
    MyCartDBContext db = new MyCartDBContext();
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.CustomerName =CustomerName;
    customer.ExtraInfo = "";
    customer.IsDeleted = false;
    db.Customers.Add(customer);
    db.SaveChanges();
    int latestCustomerId = customer.CustomerId;
    return latestCustomerId;/*ReturnCustomerId on Postback*/
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMultiOrders(int customerId)
{
    MyCartDBContext db = new MyCartDBContext();
    OrderListVM model = new OrderListVM();
    var dataJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderListVM>>(model.DataJson);

    foreach(var item in dataJson)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.OrderName = item.OrderName;
        orderCustomerId = customerId;
        order.OrderTypeId = item.OrderTypeId;
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PopulateCustomer");
}
```

The jQuery:

```
function AddInfo() {
    var cdata = {
        CustomerName: $('#customername').val()
    };
    var OrdersArr = [];
    $("#ulist > ul li").each(function (index, elem) {
        var liElem = {};
        liElem.OrderName = $("ul li .ordername").val();
        liElem.OrderNumber = $("ul li .ordernumber").val();
        OrdersArr.push(liElem);
    });
    var odata = JSON.stringify(OrdersArr);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/SaveCustomer/SaveCustomerOnlyFirst',
        data: cdata,
        success: function (customerid) {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/SaveCustomer/SaveMultiOrders/?customerid='+customerid,
                data: odata,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function () {
                    console.log("CustomerName and Orders Posted Successfully.");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("couldn't Add Orders.");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("couldn't Add CustomerName and Orders.");
        }
    });
}
```

So far, the Customer Table is only posted and then a error occurs; what is sent to `SaveMultiOrders` is null. I couldn't figure out a right way to post Orders as `DataJSON`. Would anyone please be kind and help?

Answer (score 0):

You're using query string in `url` part while AJAX `method` explicitly set to `POST`, hence an error occurred because GET controller action method with specified name not found:

```
url: '/SaveCustomer/SaveMultiOrders/?customerid='+customerid // this is GET query string
```

The AJAX callback `data` part should be modified to include both `customerId` and JSON data like this:

**AJAX (`SaveMultiOrders`)**

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'post',
     url: '/SaveCustomer/SaveMultiOrders',
     data: { customerId: customerid, dataJson: odata },
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function () {
         console.log("CustomerName and Orders Posted Successfully.");
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log("couldn't Add Orders.");
     }
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMultiOrders(int customerId, string dataJson)
{
    // JSON data processing here

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PopulateCustomer");
}
```

**Note:** You can pass `OrdersArr` directly to controller action by using `traditional: true` option in AJAX, as given below:

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'post',
     url: '/SaveCustomer/SaveMultiOrders',
     data: { customerId: customerid, ordersList: OrdersArr },
     traditional: true, // add this line
     success: function () {
         console.log("CustomerName and Orders Posted Successfully.");
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log("couldn't Add Orders.");
     }
});
```

Then change parameter type from JSON string to list of viewmodel class in controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMultiOrders(int customerId, List<OrderListVM> orderList)
{
    MyCartDBContext db = new MyCartDBContext();
    OrderListVM model = new OrderListVM();
    foreach (var item in orderList)
    {
        // data processing iteration here
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PopulateCustomer");
}
```

Comment: It didn't hit the break point on Controller:SaveCustomer Action:SaveMultiOrders
Any idea?

Comment: Try using `@Url.Action` method helper to create URL. If the AJAX POST going right, the breakpoint set inside action method should be triggered.